# Dynamic programming efficient network

Tags: dynamic-programming, directed-acyclic-graphs

Hello I have a dynamic programming  related question. How can I compute the shortest path in hops from starting node to ending, with the constrain that the vertices and edges will have an equal or higher predefined value. For example the highest rate of data in a network. Could someone provide some pseudo-code or any thoughts, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Build new graph from the given network, which does not contain the vertices and edges whose value is less than the predefined value, and from the start node, in the new graph run an algorithm to find the shortest path to the end node, such as BFS, Dijkstra (-Greedy, not Dynamic Programming), Bellman – Ford, etc.